# Jenkins doesn't update GitHub check status sometimes

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins 2.15 (GitHub plugin 1.29.3) based CI for my GitHub core repo. It works fine, but **sometimes** Jenkins build doesn't update GitHub check status.
I see nothing relevant into Jenkins log.
Any idea how to debug and hopefully fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, check status update is just an http request to the status api: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/

I experienced a similar behavior with a database. The client application and the database had no errors. Each one was on a different host.

What I did was, create a bash script in host A to perform a **ping** to host B.

```
ping www.host_B.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done >> /tmp/ping-test-$(date +%F).log
```

Then, when the sporadic error related to the connection of the database occurred, the log file helped me to detect that the error was related to:

- Network issues
- Latency issues
- Internet service provider issues

In your case, you could perform a simple curl to the status api and compare to the sporadic behavior detected.